# Using awk / grep to extract #s from database, filter

Tags: filter, awk, grep

I have a large tab-delimited database that looks like:

```
1       14933   14933   G       A       ID=COSN404397;OCCURENCE=1(lung)  
1       14948   14948   G       A       ID=COSN415697,COSN415698;OCCURENCE=2(urinary_tract)  
1       69537   69537   G       T       ID=COSM536198;OCCURENCE=1(lung)  
1       69538   69538   G       A       ID=COSM75742;OCCURENCE=1(ovary)  
...
```

I am trying to use awk or grep to keep only lines with OCCURENCE >= 3 (yes, it's misspelled throughout the database!), but I can't seem to figure out how best to split / scan the 6th column...

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then when it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short one liner that still keeps the `FS` usable:

```
$ awk -F'[(=\t;]' '$9>2' file
```

Comment: I just noticed that, another `(=` . but this time we both have `(=` :)

Comment: @Kent I made sure it `(=` today!

Answer (score 1):

this short one-liner should work for you. btw, your current example doesn't have any row with `OCCURENCE>=3` :)

```
 awk -F'OCCURENCE=|\\(' '$2>=3' file
```

well... if golfing a bit.... `(=` is the key... :D

```
awk -F'[(=]' '$3>2' file
```

Comment: You golfed too far is the OP needs to do more with the file. I'd at least keep `\t` as a `FS`.

Comment: @sudo_O but I just did a local test, with `\t` in file, my both lines worked... there is nothing written back to the `$0`, it doesn' matter if `\t` in `FS or OFS`... what do you think? am I wrong?

Comment: I meant that if the OP wanted to do something like `awk -F'[(=\t;]' '$9>2{print $2,$3,$4,$5}' file`. Leaving `\t` is probably a good idea. I didn't mean the resulting file would lose the `\t` separator if not used as `FS`. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: @sudo_O I got what u mean. I saw in the question OP mentioned awk or **grep**.  So I don't think that is the case.  But your idea is not bad at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ awk -F\; '{ if (substr($2,11,index($2,")")) >= 3) print $0; }' x.txt
```